# Using Docker for local development replacing Vagrant

Tags: docker, vagrant

I know there are a ton of hits on this topic, and I have spend some time looking at them, but just can not make a good decision.

I work on a Windows machine, and use Vagrant for development. I start my server, edit my files in the mounted /vagrant directory, hit F5 and see my changes. When I am done developing I upload the code to my server.

Problem is, I want to have the infrastructure of my server in "code" so a solution is docker with docker-compose. Now I do not know if there is a way to work with this like I work with Vagrant. It seems that I have to keep rebuilding my containers for for the changes to apply.

I don't know if I am doing something wrong, or is Docker really a product to use with ready to go code.

Comment: You don't even need docker compose. You just mount a volume of your code into the container the same way Vagrant mounts the shared folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I  want to have the infrastructure of my server in "code" so a solution is docker with docker-compose.
>   It seems that I have to keep rebuilding my containers for for the changes to apply.

As long as your [docker-compose is mounting the host folder](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-volume-driver) where your code is, you wouldn't need to rebuild your container "for the changes to apply": that container would see any code changes immediately, without having to restart it.

Comment: I think I have tried this, but not got it succesfully working. I will try this ones again I guess, must have been doing something wrong. Will report back soon.